Laptop display is blank when using NVIDIA gpu
having some trouble with the graphics on my Asus PX13 which I got last week. I need to use some NVIDIA Omniverse applications for work and those require an rtx GPU to be present. I would like to be able to use the GPU and have my laptop display work.
After installing all of the recommended NVIDIA graphics drivers and rebooting, it will freeze on the splash screen. If I use nomodeset in grub boot settings, the system will boot, however the laptop display will be blank. I can get graphics if I use an external monitor connected through HDMI, although it is quite inconvenient.
The laptop display can't be found in settings or nvidia-settings.
The same result occurs if prime-select on-demand or NVIDIA are used.
A few things I've tried:
I messed around with prime-select intel to switch to integrated graphics to see if it was possible to just use the GPU for specific applications, however the GPU becomes blacklisted and I couldn't get it to work, although the laptop display does work and the external monitor does not.
I've reinstalled various driver versions (535, 540, 545, 550, 555 and 560), tried the ones directly from NVIDIA, and various versions of Ubuntu (22.04 and 24.04), gcc and cuda toolkit. Currently running Ubuntu 24.04, gcc 13.2 and cuda 12.4 with the 550 NVIDIA drivers from ubuntu.
I have tried deleting the xorg.conf files, however this produced no results
Have tried blacklisting disabling the nouveau drivers, had no effect

I'm quite lost on where to go now, any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Hi, I'm interested in this as well. I'm planning to get a PX13 and run ubuntu on it. How is your overall ubuntu experience? We're you able to fix this?

I met the same problems, then installed ubuntu 24.10 It's not perfect, but it works.
I participate on a thread on reddit about it. I will copy here some of the comments I posted.
In the meantime, here is a link to the discussion: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/1f72smd/anyone_who_tried_the_asus_proart_px13_hn7306/
My "pseudo" there is "vegetable_money".
